# How can I set connection for Query builder in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I want to use QueryBuilder:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();
```

with non-default connection:

```
\Yii::$app->get('db_mysql')
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: you want to set a  new connection

Comment: i gave you the solution for new connection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all(\Yii::$app->db_mysql);
```

Of course, you have to set `db_mysql` component in your config

Doc:

```
/**
 * Executes the query and returns all results as an array.
 * @param Connection $db the database connection used to generate the SQL statement.
 * If this parameter is not given, the `db` application component will be used.
 * @return array the query results. If the query results in nothing, an empty array will be returned.
 */
public function all($db = null)
{
    $rows = $this->createCommand($db)->queryAll();
    return $this->populate($rows);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model create method

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\Connection the database connection used by this AR class.
 */
public static function getDb()
{
    return Yii::$app->get('db_mysql');
}
```

after that

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all(YourModel::getDb());
```

or

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('id, name')
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->all(static::getDb());
```

in YourModel context